# Injecting environment variables to string path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following string :

```
some_string = "%envvar1%\location\execution.exe"
```

envvar1 is an environment variable with value of "c:\", and I would like some function as following:

```
some_string = "%envvar1%\location\execution.exe"
inject_env_variable(some_string)
print(some_string)
"c:\location\execution.exe"
```

Creating a function like this wouldnt be to difficult with regular expressions and os.environ but I was wondering if there was some kind of built in module that treats these kind of things.

**Note:** google searching anything with the word 'path' and 'python' is really tedious since all the searches are related to pythonpath :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.expandvars` is probably what you are looking for. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os


def inject_env_variable(s):
   return s.replace("%envvar1%", os.environ['envvar1'])
```

Should do the trick